# Difference between Func<T, Task> and anonymous async await Action<T>

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor

I am developing on ASP.NET Core Blazor and sometimes I look on GitHub to learn something. This question isn't strictly related to Blazor, but I saw a lot of Blazor developers doing what I am going to explain.

I noticed that some components accept an `Action<T>` as a parameter and others accept a `Func<T, Task>`.

```cs
/* example */

public class MyComponentA : ComponentBase 
{
    [Parameter] public Action<T> OnClick {get; set;}

    //... other methods
}

public class MyComponentB : ComponentBase 
{
    [Parameter] public Func<T, Task> OnClickAsync {get; set;}

    //... other methods
}
```

What I understood is that you should bind `Action<T>` to a **no-async/await** method and `Func<T, Task>` to an **async/method**. So far so good.

However, I see that someone is used to pass an ***async/await anonymous function*** as `Action<T>`, like `OnClick=@(async (item) => await Foo(item))`. Sometimes, I have passed an anonymous async/await function as `Action` too, and it works.

- Is it correct?
- Is there any kind of side effect?
- Is an `Action<T>` that invokes an anonymous async/await function, an asynchronous call?

Comment: `Action` is a delegate that doesn't have a return value; `Func` is a delegate that has a return value. Which one you use has no bearing on whether or not a particular method executes asynchronously.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/884561/kenneth-k So why some developers say something like "now, with Func<T, Task> our components accept asynchronous methods. UI-thread won't be blocked by our component". Following your answer, it seems that this quote doesn't have any sense. It seems like that Func<T, Task> is a better way to accepts async/await methods without use an async/await anonymous method.

Answer (score 8):

`Action<T>` does not allow a return value, and only methods that return an [awaitable type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#awaitable-expressions) (usually `Task` or `Task<T>`) can be awaited.

Therefore, if you use pass an asynchronous method as `Action<T>` it will **always** be fire and forget.

Using `Func` with `Task` as a return value **may** be awaited, depending on how the method is implemented.

Comment: Fire and Forget only applies to async methods since they relinquish control of the thread at some point and if not awaited the code after it will not be in a continuation.  However with a sync method the entire code will be run before the thread continues with any code that comes after it.

Comment: @juharr yes, maybe not the best wording; I'll update.

Comment: In the Blazor context, awaiting `Func<T, Task>` can be extremely useful since it allows the developer to then fire `StateHasChanged()` to update the UI with the effects of the function in place.

Comment: @Rich can I ask you to show me an example? Thank you!

Comment: I don't have one handy, but think about it - you don't know when the results of a fire and forget call are complete and you don't really care.  Because you can await the `Task` returned from a Func (although honestly, C# needs a `Unit` type), you know it's completed and can safely call StateHasChanged.

Comment: Fire and forget applies to `Task`s. In case of an `async void` method there no `Task`, so there is nothing to be forgotten. The difference is apparent in how exceptions are treated. A faulted fire-and-forget `Task` triggers the [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception) event, without other consequences. A faulted async void triggers the [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception) event and then the process is terminated.

Answer (score 7):

> Sometimes, I have passed an anonymous async/await function as Action too, and it works.

It *compiles*.

What actually happens is that the `async` lambda is converted to an `async void` method by the compiler, and [`async void` methods are problematic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming).

> Is it correct? Is there any kind of side effect?

It is probably not correct.

If the delegate is just a "notification", then it's essentially an event, and `async void` is usually acceptable for events. The question is: how does Blazor know that its work is done? [Blazor does have a `SynchronizationContext`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c74e9efd0e6ea5b4d6737d23b92042772a50a249/src/Components/Components/src/Rendering/RendererSynchronizationContext.cs); however, its `SynchronizationContext` does not [detect `async void` handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2011/february/msdn-magazine-parallel-computing-it-s-all-about-the-synchronizationcontext). So Blazor may decide that its work is done when it actually has more work to do.

> Is an Action that invokes an anonymous async/await function, an asynchronous call?

Yes, but it is `async void`, so it doesn't *appear* asynchronous. E.g., there is no way for the delegate invoker to know when the delegate has completed executing.